# igraph "Not a graph object"

Tags: r, igraph

I intend to get some statistics on a network using the igraph package.

```
model1 <- ug(~a:b, ~a:c:d,~b:c)
> model1
A graphNEL graph with undirected edges
Number of Nodes = 4 
Number of Edges = 5
```

Problem: using the function:

```
cluster.distribution(model1)
```

returns

```
Error in cluster.distribution(model1) : Not a graph object.
```

Now if I apply the function:

```
degree(model1)
```

i get the same error:

```
Error in degree(model1) : Not a graph object
```

however if I detach the igraph package i get:

```
> detach("package:igraph", unload=TRUE)
Warning message:
'igraph' namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace 'igraph' is imported by 'gRbase', 'gRain' so cannot be unloaded 
> degree(model1)
a b c d 
3 2 3 2
```

I assume the problem is related the the packages, but my R skill don't go so far as that I would be able to figure this problem out by myself.

```
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"       "package:gRain"    "package:grid"    
 [4] "package:gRbase"   "package:graph"    "tools:rstudio"   
 [7] "package:stats"    "package:utils"    "package:datasets"
 [10] "package:methods"  "Autoloads"        "package:base"
```

I am really interested in using the function from the igraph package so please help me figure out why I get this error even though it is obviously a graph object.

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use the `graph` package and the `igraph` packages. Objects created with one can't be used in functions from the other, it seems.

The `igraph` objects are of class `igraph`

```
> g=graph.full(4)
> class(g)
[1] "igraph"
```

whereas the object you created with `ug` has come from the `graph` package and so is a different class.

I'd test this myself, but currently the `graph` package has been removed from CRAN and I'm not in the mood to go chasing it from the archives:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/graph/index.html

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. It seems that there is a known bug with the igraph package. https://github.com/igraph/igraph/commit/0567c2694a99686bbd1855299822ad52dcd5989a however I could not figure out how to solve it. My skillsare not good enough.

Comment: No, that bug does not have anything to do with your question.

Comment: @Spacedman: the graph package is on BioConductor: http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/graph.html

Comment: @VincentGrunert: use the `igraph.from.graphNEL` function to convert `model1` to an igraph object. http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/graphNEL.html

Comment: @GaborCsardi can I send you an email, there are actually  few more problems. However I love you package! And many thanks for answering my query.

Comment: @GaborCsardi: you are of course right there are two problems: one to change it to an igraph object, which I already did by: model1 <- as(model1, "igraph"). Then there is the issue about the degree.distibution and cluster.distribution functions, where I get the error: "> cluster.distribution(model1)
Error in cluster.distribution(model1) : could not find function "hist""

Comment: and last: trying to install the latest version of the package on mac osx 10.6.8 through terminal i get: "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 144/145/259: make: command not found" checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/B-/B-vij4PvG1K9q1Uv2RID9k+++TI/-Tmp-/RtmpM2WfQm/R.INSTALL38e5bff9452/igraph':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘igraph’

Comment: If you have problems, then you can ask questions here, on StackOverflow, or post to the igraph-help mailing list. Thanks.